# How to fix NoNode error - storm kafka?

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am working on storm and kafka. I am using [this](https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test) project.

#### Note

I am running this project locally. It is throwing following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:87) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3284$fn__3299.invoke(executor.clj:520) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:429) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:94) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/clickstreamlog/partitions
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1586) ~[zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5-1392090]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[curator-client-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38) ~[curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:na]
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:91) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Anyone faced the same issue using [storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test](https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test) project.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

this error in current context signify, that zookeeper is not being able to automatically create any/all of following nodes - 
**storm-kafka, storm, zookeeper**

You may try out creating the nodes manually on the zookeeper, I think that will work for u.